# While loop for Teradata

Tags: loops, teradata

world.

I'm try to find a way to compile multiple events together.  Data looks like this:

[image: Existing Data]

Basically, it is series of row data with event logs

I want to generate an aggregation of these row events such that if a new event occurred within 30 seconds of the other ending, it combines the time together.  However, if the event log does not have an abutting event, then it is not captured.   And these events are 'person' specific.

I envision the output to look something like this:

[image: Output data]

My intuition suggests using some kind of while loop, but I'm not sure where to start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need for recursion (and very hard to write) or a loop over a cursor.

```
SELECT
   Person,
   Min(starttime),
   Max(starttime),
   -- get a concatenated string
   Trim(Trailing ',' FROM (XmlAgg(Reason || ',' ORDER BY Reason ) (VARCHAR(1000))))
FROM
 (
   SELECT Person, Start_timestamp, Stop_timestamp, Reason,
     -- assign the same number to all rows within 30 seconds 
     Sum(flag) Over
     Over (PARTITION BY Person
           ORDER BY Start_timestamp
           ROWS Unbounded Preceding) AS grp
   FROM
    (
      SELECT Person, Start_timestamp, Stop_timestamp, Reason,
         -- check if previous end is within 30 seconds of the current start
         CASE WHEN Lag(Stop_timestamp) 
                   Over (PARTITION BY Person
                         ORDER BY Start_timestamp) + INTERVAL '30' SECOND < Start_timestamp
              THEN 0
              ELSE 1
         END AS flag
      FROM tab
    ) AS dt
 ) AS dt
-- aggregate per person and group
GROUP BY Person, grp
```

If your Teradata version supports `SESSIONIZE` you can simplify the group calculation, but I couldn't write this syntaxc ad hoc :-)

Comment: This works pretty close to what I'm hoping for.  Thank you dnoeth.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using `RECURSIVE CTE`

```
WITH RECURSIVE MYREC(Person,Start_timestamp,Stop_timestamp ,Reason,LVL)
 AS(
 SELECT Person,MIN(Start_timestamp),MAX(Stop_timestamp),MIN(Reason)(varchar(100)) AS Reason,1
 FROM MYTABLE
 GROUP BY 1

 UNION ALL

 SELECT b.Person,b.Start_timestamp,b.Stop_timestamp ,trim(a.Reason) || ',' || trim( b.Reason), LVL+1
 FROM MYTABLE a INNER JOIN MYREC b
 ON a.Person = b.Person
 AND a.Reason > b.Reason
 )

 SELECT Person,Start_timestamp,Stop_timestamp,Reason
 FROM MYREC
 QUALIFY RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY Person ORDER BY Reason DESC) = 1
```

Change `MYTABLE` to your tablename